# NetBeans Platform Application Branding Name Limitations

Tags: java, netbeans-7, rcp, netbeans-platform

I really like the NetBeans Platform framework, but it has some "weird/hidden" features and finding the documentation for most things is almost impossible. I hope that this will change in the future as it would make everything easier.

Now to my question, please take a look at the following screenshot:
[image]

As you can see the NetBeans is reporting that the "Application name is not valid". For the name to be valid it must be "myapp" or "my_app". When you package the project as a windows installer and you install the application it will install it as:

C:\Program Files\myapp or C:\Program Files\my_app

Well, what if I want to use Uppercase letters or Spaces how would I do this? For example

C:\Program Files\MY Application Blah blah

Comment: I don't think this is possible, of-course you can use uppercase without any issues

Comment: I just tried the uppercase again and it is reporting it as invalid, I tried MYAPP

Comment: Then I think it's not possible

Answer (score 1):

Try manually editing your application's `project.properties` file.

Change one line from

```
app.name=${branding.token}
```

to

```
app.name=MY Application Blah blah
```

At least on Mac, this approach yields a better menu bar app name, and probably a better app bundle name.